# Deploying to Heroku with existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Currently on Ch 2 of Hartl's tutorial in which I make a simple app with users and microposts.

I add a few users and microposts to the database.

Near the end of the chapter, it gets you to deploy the app to Heroku. When I view the app on Heroku however, there are no users or microposts anymore.

How do I get the existing data to be deployed as well?

Comment: What is your local database?

Comment: @soundar i think it's sqlite3

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has different database than your app locally. So every data you created in the local app will not be pushed to Heroku when you run `git push heroku master`

I would create a database dump (maybe the Seed Dump is interesting) so you can import this in Heroku or you could place the `users` and `microposts` in a seed file and run `heroku run rake db:seed`

http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data gives an brief explanation on how you could seed the db

Answer (score 1):

Use [YamlDb](https://github.com/yamldb/yaml_db) gem to dump data to a `yaml` file.

**Create data dump by:**

```
rake db:data:dump   ->   Dump contents of Rails database to db/data.yml
```

**Push code to Heroku:**

```
git push heroku master
```

**Load data to heroku database:**

```
heroku run rake db:data:load   ->   Load contents of db/data.yml into the database
```

Comment: I tried this, but running `heroku run rake db:data:load` returns `Don't know how to build task 'db:data:load'`

Comment: did you add the gem in your `Gemfile` ?

Comment: yes i typed `gem 'yaml_db'` in gemfile. This is the error message I get: `/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in<top (required)>'` Is it possible cos I'm using ruby 2.3.1?

Comment: the error message is not complete. can you paste the complete error log somewhere (like paste bin) ?

Comment: Add gem to your Gemfile. The run `bundle install`. Then `bundle exec rake db:data:dump `

Comment: Done that. Also pushed to heroku and ran `heroku run rake db:data:load` again. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Does it matter if I'm using sqlite?

Comment: can you share your code via github. i will look into the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're using postgres you can push your local database to your heroku app doing the following:

Checkout your config/database.yml file to see what the development database is named.  For this example I'll call it cool_development.  Then once you have run:

```
git push heroku master
```

Then run the migrations to create the database:  `heroku run rake db:migrate`
Then push your database to heroku:  `heroku pg:push cool_development DATABASE_URL --app app_name_here`

The database heroku creates for you is accessed using the DATABASE_URL environment variable so you don't need to change anything in the above line except for the local database name unless your app is named 'cool' lol.